# NumPy column change value or add

Tags: python, numpy

I have written a code like the following:

```
# weight shape will be as (108, 796)
Weight = np.zeros((xm_a*xm_b,data1_a))

# tt shape will be as (108, 1)
tt = np.reshape(AR[:,:,i].T,(AR_a*AR_b,1),order='F')

for i ...:
   ...
   Weight[:,i] = tt
```

When running the code, the following error will be appeared relating to the last line:

> ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (108,1) into
> shape (108,)

So how to solve this problem? I'm new to python.

Comment: Your question needs some example data and must be written better. It is confusing. I write a solution from my understanding from the question.

Comment: Hi @camlove, if my answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding from the question, we can create an example data like:

```
Weight = np.array([[3, 4], [4, 2], [6, 3]])
tt = np.array([[7], [17], [177]])
```

Now, we can substitute columnar in *Weight* with new *tt* one using:

```
for i in range(2):
    Weight[:, i] = tt[:, 0]
```

where *Weight* will be changed as follows, based on *tt*:

> new Weight = np.array([[7, 7], [17, 17], [177, 177]])

For when *tt* will changes during loops, e.g. if:

```
tt = [np.array([[7], [17], [177]]), np.array([[5], [15], [155]])]
```

we can substitute columnar in *Weight* with each sub-tt in *tt* list using:

```
for i, j in enumerate(tt):
    Weight[:, i] = j[:, 0]
```

which will result in new *Weight* as:

> new Weight = np.array([[7, 5], [17, 15], [177, 155]])